# Получение данных из mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу программу на C++, есть работа с PhP частью
Нужно вывести число из Базы Данных.
При корректном подключении идёт такое окно:

[image: Корректное подключение]

в php прописывал echo 'true'; для проверки работы

Щас решил вывести количество оставшихся дней в программу
Закоменчиваю echo 'true';, и прописываю следующий код:

```
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `date` FROM `keyact`');
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo "{$result['date']}<br>";
        }
```

Но теперь программа не может соединиться с сервером, и выводит Error Key (по типу ошибки подключения)
Полный код
https://pastebin.com/7GztFz67

[image: Ошибка соединения]

Comment: `SELECT__пробел__` Что такое `$db`, где определяется?

Comment: $db - подключение к базе данных

Comment: Откройте ваш php-скрипт в браузере/запустите в консоли и смотрите что происходит. К с++ вопрос вообще не имеет отношения.

Comment: В браузере отображается другая часть кода "Ошибка: Отсутствует привязка."  (я добавил полный код выше)

Comment: `mysql` и `mysqli` (`i` в конце) - это __совершенно разные API__.

Comment: Поменял, но ничего не изменилось. Подключения так и нет

Comment: Поменяли что на что? Мне попытаться угадать?

Comment: mysqli на mysql

Comment: А аргументы в функциях поменяли?

Comment: Вроде как да, но это не точно. Я в php не очень хорошо разбираюсь